# Can we get input from user and store it into a variable inside a oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am new to oracle and pl/sql...I am trying to make a pl/sql snippet for train booking.. Before inserting the data into the main table I have a series of checks..

My SP goes like this:

```
create or replace procedure sp_booking
is
pr_usr_id number(23);
pr_train_no number(23);
pr_class varchar(35);
req_qty_seats number(3);
pr_food_check varchar(10);
pr_food_type varchar(60);
begin
select v('user_id'), v('train_no'), v('class'), v('quantity') into pr_usr_id, pr_train_no, pr_class, req_qty_seats from dual;
select FOOD into pr_food_check from train_details where train_no=pr_train_no;
if pr_food_check = 'Y' then
select v('food_type') into pr_food_type from dual;
dbms_output.put_line('sorry this train does not provide food!');
end if;

if fn_availability(req_qty_seats, pr_class)='Y' then

insert into booking (booking_id, user_id, train_no, class, quantity, food_type) values (booking_sq.nextval, pr_usr_id, pr_train_no, pr_class, req_qty_seats, pr_food_type);

else

insert into booking (booking_id, user_id, train_no, class, quantity, food_type) values (booking_sq.nextval, pr_usr_id, pr_train_no, pr_class, req_qty_seats, 'null'); 
end if;

end sp_booking;
```

My question is     select v('user_id'), v('train_no'), v('class'), v('quantity') into pr_usr_id, pr_train_no, pr_class, req_qty_seats from dual;
will this code get value from user and store it in the variables declared ?
When I execute the SP it says "ORA-01403: no data found" please help..
P.S. I am using apex.oracle.com for working on this..

Comment: A stored procedure is not interactive.  It has no way to interact with a user.  It can't ask for input.  And you shouldn't assume that a user would ever see anything you write to `dbms_output`, certainly not if you're building an APEX application.  Your APEX application can interact with the user, it can display messages, and it can pass parameters to the procedure.

Comment: Thanks Justin! can you suggest me an alternate way for getting input from the user and passing it inside the SP ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off writing this as a function, then passing the Apex application items/variable as parameters.  The function should return the value, which you can parse in Apex to determine success/failure.

Here's how I'd write the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_booking(pr_usr_id     IN VARCHAR2,
                                      pr_train_no   IN VARCHAR2,
                                      pr_class      IN VARCHAR2,
                                      req_qty_seats IN PLS_INTEGER,
                                      pr_food_type  IN VARCHAR2) RETURNING VARCHAR2 IS
    pr_food_check VARCHAR(10);
    ret_status_msg VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
    SELECT food
      INTO pr_food_check
      FROM train_details
     WHERE train_no = pr_train_no;

    IF pr_food_check = 'Y'
    THEN
        ret_status_msg := 'sorry this train does not provide food!';
    END IF;

    IF fn_availability(req_qty_seats, pr_class) = 'Y'
    THEN

        INSERT INTO booking
            (booking_id,
             user_id,
             train_no,
             CLASS,
             quantity,
             food_type)
        VALUES
            (booking_sq.nextval,
             pr_usr_id,
             pr_train_no,
             pr_class,
             req_qty_seats,
             pr_food_type);
        ret_status_msg := '1 Booking w/ Food created';
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO booking
            (booking_id,
             user_id,
             train_no,
             CLASS,
             quantity,
             food_type)
        VALUES
            (booking_sq.nextval,
             pr_usr_id,
             pr_train_no,
             pr_class,
             req_qty_seats,
             'null');
        ret_status_msg := '1 Booking w/ NO Food created';
    END IF;

END sp_booking;
```

In Apex, you need to create a page item to hold the returned message from the function, then create a process that calls the function, probably when a Submit button is clicked.

I hope that's enough help to get you going.